# Issue with varbinary(max) datatype in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, query-performance

I have created a table having two columns with datatype `varbinary(max)`. I am saving pdf files in binary format in these columns. There is no issue while inserting the pdf files in these columns. But when I am selecting even a single record with only one column of type `varbinary` in `select` query it takes around one minute to fetch the record. The size of pdf file inserted is of 1MB. Here is the sql query to fetch single record:

```
select binarypdffile from gm_packet where jobpacketid=1
```

Kindly suggest if there is a way to improve the performance with `varbinary` datatype.

Comment: which version are you using 2008, 2008 R2 or 2014?

Comment: can you add the schema and indexes for the table `gm_packet`

Comment: What kind of network connection is this? That's about the only realistic cause for this that I can imagine.

Comment: @ughai , thanks for your response. I am using both 2008 R2 and 2014. If I will add the index on gm_packet then inserting will be very slow as index in always rearranged at the time of insertion.

Comment: @usr I am just executing the sql query in SSMS and its taking too much time to fetch this record.

Comment: @RajbirSingh - can you add the table structure and existing indexes in your question, it will help you in getting better answers. Also add stats about column `jobpacketid`

Comment: And what kind network connection is this? How fast is it? Is it high latency? Your comment did not address my question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try and time the following queries:

```
SELECT cnt = COUNT(*) INTO #test1 FROM gm_packet WHERE jobpacketid = 1

SELECT binarypdffile INTO #test2 FROM gm_packet WHERE jobpacketid = 1
```

The first one tests how long it takes to find the record. If it's slow, add an index on the jobpacketid field. Assuming these values come in sequentially I wouldn't worry about performance as records get added in the future. Otherwise you might need to rebuild the index once in a while.

The second tests how long it takes to fetch the data from the table (and store it back into another table). Since no data goes out of 'the system' it should show 'raw database performance' without any "external" influence.

Neither should be very long. If they aren't but it still takes 'a long time' to run your original query in SSMS and get the binary data in the grid, then I'm guessing it's either a network issue (wifi?) or SSMS simply is very bad at representing the blob in the GUI; it's been noticed before =)